# How to send email after a new DynamoDB entry without Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I would normally handle the task of sending an email after a new DynamoDB entry with Lambda and SES but I'm required to not use Lambda for it.
There's a 'Contact us' section in the website and the email needs to be sent every time a new entry is made. We use API Gateway to post the data to DyanmoDB
Is there a way to carry this out without Lambda?

Comment: You use api gateway to post data in DynamoDB. Do you integrate apigw and ddb together without lambda?

Comment: Yes. I don't use Lambda.

Comment: why don't you use Lambda? Lambda makes life easy by integrating with tons of AWAS services. By not using it, you may unnecessarily complicate establishing integration with other AWS services. But you do you.

Comment: That's the requirement, I'd love to use Lambda but I can't.

Comment: Maybe I haven't udnerstood the question but why can't an email be sent using eventbridge? You can tailor your input(when a record is added to dynamodb) and select sns as the target...

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without writing code. Furthermore you may probably want to tailor each email to make it more personal to the user, thus Lambda is a must.

You could design something using EventBridge Pipes which can trigger when a new user is added and can have SNS as a destination which could trigger an email. But that email may not be customizable nor may it send to people not subscribed to the topic

Comment: The receiver of email is a single gmail account and the format of the email should be a generic message involving the name of the user, email address and the message.
Can I do that with the way you described?

Comment: EventBridge Pipe and SNS topic will suit your needs, no code needed

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB triggers Lambda functions by feeding the records of a DynamoDB Stream to the Lambda function. That is by far the easiest way to process updates to a DynamoDB table, but you can also write other code that processes a DynamoDB outside of Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it without writing code? For example with Cloudwatch Events.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it without lambda you can use the following pattern and glue some AWS services together.

You can consume the dynamodb stream with [eventbridge pipes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-event-target.html) and send it to a stepfunction and there you use the [sdk integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html) to call SES. Instead of stepfunction you can directly use SNS for simpler setups.

You will not have to use lambda for this setup. Further you can transform your message either in the pipe or in the stepfunction.

Be aware that eventbirdge pipes has currently no AWS CDK L2 construct which might make it harder to configure if you use CDK.